# How do I enter login details and get the data behind the login page

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient, html-agility-pack

So I was searching for some fixes to get my code to work but I couldn't find anything that worked. I have to sign in to get the data from another page.

Here is my code:

```
string pageSource;
string formUrl = "http://aldoc.tc/Sys/Login.srf?Page=DefaultLogin&Cult=en";
string formParams = string.Format("catalogus={0}&gebruikersnaam={1}&wachtwoord={2}", "blabla", "blabla", "blabla");
string cookieheader;

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.CookieContainer = cookies;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
cookieheader = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

string getUrl = "http://aldoc.tc/Sys/AldocSys.srf";
HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
// [HK] use the same cookiecontainer as on the first request - correct
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
getRequest.Method = "GET";
getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
// [HK] no need to add cookies, they should be there already
//cookies.Add(getResponse.Cookies);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
// [HK] no need to add cookies, they should be there already
// cookies.Add(getResponse.Cookies);



var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(getUrl);

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

try
{
    foreach (var cell4 in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3"))
    {


        string Test = cell4.InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(Test);

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I tested the code and I saw that `cookieheader = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];` is null. I think that is the problem.

Can anyone help me please?

edit:

I added a cookie to the httpclient but it still didn't work.
I added the cookie like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://aldoc.tc/Sys/AldocSys.srf");
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

handler.CookieContainer.Add(uri, new Cookie("name", "value")); // Adding a Cookie
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
CookieCollection collection2 = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri); // Retrieving a Cookie
```

edit 2:

I fixed it so that I have the html of the page I want, but now I can't see the things inside the frames.

```
        string pageSource;
        //inlogpagina
        string formUrl = "http://aldoc.tc/Sys/Login.srf?Page=DefaultLogin&Cult=en";
        string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}", "blabla", "blabla");

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.CookieContainer = cookies;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        CookieCollection collection = cookies.GetCookies(req.RequestUri);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }



        //Haalt de SysSession value op
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        var html = pageSource;

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        var cell4 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script");

        string Test = cell4.InnerText;
        //SysSession value
        Test = Test.Substring(27, 16);




        //Sessiepagina
        string getUrl = "http://aldoc.tc/Sys/Info.srf?SysSession=" + Test + "";
        string formParams2 = string.Format("SysSession={0}", Test);
        HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);

        req2.CookieContainer = cookies;
        req2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req2.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams2);
        req2.ContentLength = bytes2.Length;
        using (Stream os = req2.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp2 = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse();

        CookieCollection collection2 = cookies.GetCookies(req2.RequestUri);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }




        //Mainpagina
        string getUrl2 = "http://aldoc.tc/Sys/AldocSys.srf/";
        string formParams3 = string.Format("SysSession={0}&hostname={1}", Test, "aldoc.tc");
        HttpWebRequest req3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl2);

        req3.CookieContainer = cookies;
        req3.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req3.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req3.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes3 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams3);
        req3.ContentLength = bytes3.Length;
        using (Stream os = req3.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes3, 0, bytes3.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp3 = (HttpWebResponse)req3.GetResponse();

        CookieCollection collection3 = cookies.GetCookies(req3.RequestUri);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp3.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        HttpClientHandler handler2 = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(handler2);

        var html2 = pageSource;

        var htmlDocument2 = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument2.LoadHtml(html2);

        var cell5 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td");
        Console.WriteLine(cell5.InnerText);
```

This is the output of the pageSource:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"                   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AldocSys</title>
<meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com                    /intellisense/ie5" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"  />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src='/AldocJs/Aldoc.js?Time=1501061949'></script>
<script src='/AldocJs/Car.js?Time=1490343019'></script>
<script src='Xlate.srf?Cult=nl&Page=AldocSys&Time=1504093438'></script>
<script src='/AldocJs/AldocSys.js?Time=1501065406'></script>
<script src='/AldocJs/Srvr/AldocSys.js?Time=1495005368'></script>
<script src='/AldocJs/AldocSysJN.js?Time=1436857551'></script>
<!-- InvalidHandle (2l) D:\Sys\Js\AldocSysMR.js -->
<!-- InvalidHandle (2l) D:\Sys\Js\AldocSysMR.js -->

<!-- <script src="/MMT/PicModelGet.ashx?V=20160704"></script> -->
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var   Session="gCQ8LN9mxSordc3E",NonPersist=0,Product="AldocSys",Product2="AldocSys  ";
var Login="tc•blabla",Cult="nl",DebNr=81214,Secur=8;
var MenuName="TC-SA 2017",MenuTime=1507560094,Immat=0;
var   CustID="711003",LastName="",Company="KCPerformance",Email="",Email2="",OrderE  ml="";
var KTypMask=65536,NTypMask=131072;
var bExpBox=false,SysUri="/Sys",bAtz=false,TruckUri=" /Truck",PicUri="https://pic2.aldoc.eu/PicData/";
var bCatBoxHandler=false;
var  ShowFlags=19,ShowFilter=1,ShowGnrs=2,ShowVnrs=4,ShowOnrs=8,ByArtGrp=16,HidePr ys0=32,HidePrys1=64,HidePrys2=128;
oCntxt["SysSession"]="gCQ8LN9mxSordc3E";
oCntxt["hostname"]="aldoc.tc";

var ueSession=encodeURIComponent(Session);
oNoteDef.bKent=true;
Last.newsdate=forceInt(1457533934);
Last.newsdelay=forceInt(1476182219);
Last.newsupdate=forceInt(1457533934);
Time=1507705603;Last.tick=Time;

try{ServerScript();}catch(e){;}
var CatCultDebNr="Cat"+Cult+"/c"+(("00000"+DebNr).slice(-5))+"/";
fnCntxt();window.setTimeout("fnFill();",200);
var LoginCat=(Login.split("•"))[0];
var LoginUsr=(Login.split("•"))[1];
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<frameset id="lings" cols="185,*,0,0,0,0" frameborder="0"  framespacing="0" border="0">
<frame name="SuperMenu" id="SuperMenu" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize" src="S.srf?Page=Blank" />
<frameset id="regs" rows="*,0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
<frame name="Content" id="Content" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize"  src="S.srf?Page=Blank" />
```

Comment: Do you have to sign in when using a Webrowser Manually?  If you have to with a webbrowser then there is nothing you can do differently in a script.  The web page would have to change to use network credentials in stead of requiring a user to login;

Comment: Yes, you have to sign in manually.

Comment: Is it the use of the `HttpClient` that fails? You haven't added the session cookie to it.

Comment: It fails when it tries to get the h3, so I think you are right. This is my first time working with cookies so I don't exactly know how they work in c#.

Comment: I think you need to add a certificate to your webbrowser.  Once the webbrowser is working than you application will use same certificate.

Comment: @Crowcoder the added cookie to the httpclient didn't fix it.

Comment: @jdweng and adding the certificate didn't work either.

Comment: Then I think you did it wrong :). I have [an old blog post](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/authenticating-to-asp-net-membership-provider-programmatically/) about using cookie containers. It's about the Asp.Net Forms membership, and doesn't use HttpClient, but there should still be relevant content.

Comment: Did the certificate work with the webbrowser?

Comment: @jdweng Nope it didn't.

Comment: I would first get to work with browser before getting the code working.  Check with your MIS to determine if the website supports using without typing login info.

Comment: @jdweng I don't know what MIS is.

Comment: See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_system